# How to choose right design solution for application?

Tags: asynchronous, design-patterns, apache-kafka, architecture, bigdata

Currently i am creating a design for a new enterprise application. Right now we have a lot of different proprietary solution and we wanna create a new one to switch from them all.

Briefly it is a kind of data destribution system. We have a lot of clients who needs a lot of different data.
What do i want:
1) Common REST API service
2) Some synchronoyu(async?) enviroment to send task and get data back. On image below you could see i think to use spring kafka request/reply template. It helps to scale my application in future.
3) Different typec of calculators for every kind of data

[image: img]

I search a lot how to do the second point the best way but didn't find any ready solutions or advices. Is it good to use kafka here? Maybe some one could give me advice about best practice in such situations.
Plz, send me links for articles or something else, because it will be a big application and i wanna start to create it rightly from the beginning.

Comment: Why do you need Kafka to handle such synchronous use cases? Using only http is most of the time a better idea than using Kafka for synchronous jobs. Kafka is not synchronous by nature. Could you give us more details regarding why do you need Kafka? If this is just for scaling, you might prefer using other solutions more suitable for synchronous jobs

Comment: @Yannick
Thank you for your answer. That's why i created this topic, i really don't think kafka the best way to resolve this task. 
I should to say some of this calculators could do they job asynchronous and send result to client side. For such jobs kafka will be a good decision.
But i really need some advices about synchronous scalable solutions for other part of this application.
My app could have 2 or more interfaces (kafka...others protocolos/tools to distribute task).